# Select range and replace characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make a vba to select in a sheet range and then in text replace certain characters defined in a list.

Search for (range)Sheet1, replace for value in column Sheet2 A1:A30 characters to replace, replace for Sheet B1:B30 new value.

I'm trying this but as you probably see it is not working.

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    xTitleId = "Speciale Karakters"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Opzoeken in...", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opzoeken en vervangen").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range ("A30:B30")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=rng.Value, replacement:=rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? If there is an error, include its number and description and on which line it occurs in your post. Why are you using `A30:B30` instead of `A1:B30`? Replace (combine) `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opzoeken en vervangen").Activate` which is not a range and `ActiveSheet.Range ("A30:B30")` which is not an expression, to get `Set ReplaceRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opzoeken en vervangen").Range("A1:B30")`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. That’s  mistyped idd that should be A1:A:30. It is telling me missing object when executed .

Answer (score 0):

- I guess Range("A30:B30") is a typo in your code. Is it Range("A1:B30") ?
- It is not necessary to activate a sheet in order to reference a range on that sheet.

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    xTitleId = "Speciale Karakters"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Opzoeken in...", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opzoeken en vervangen").Range("A1:B30")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=rng.Value, replacement:=rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```